# Print Non-latin charaters in powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd, python-3.7

I am a newbie to this so excuse if my Q is "dumb". 
I have a .txt file which has some non-latin script in it (Arabic, Hindi, japanese, etc). These characters are showing fine when i open in notepad. However if i try to print them (raw data) in cmd prompt window or windows powershell, they appear as boxes or Q marks. 
I am reading some websites but finding some conflicting info - are non-latin scripts NOT supported on the above consoles?

Comment: What command are you using to have them printed in Powershell? `Get-Content`?

Comment: What is the font that you are using in notepad, and what font are you using in the console?

Comment: I didnt know we can modify fonts in notepad?! The console font is Lucida console.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the `-Encoding` on the command that you call the `*.txt` file with (if it supports it).

```
Get-Content C:\temp\test2.txt
à¤¸à¥à¤Ÿà¥ˆà¤• à¤“à¤µà¤°à¤«à¤¼à¥à¤²à¥‹
ÙƒÙˆÙ…Ø© Ø£ÙƒØ«Ø± Ù…Ù† Ø§Ù„ØªØ¯ÙÙ‚
ã‚¹ã‚¿ãƒƒã‚¯ã‚ªãƒ¼ãƒãƒ¼ãƒ•ãƒ­ãƒ¼

Get-Content C:\temp\test2.txt -Encoding UTF8
स्टैक ओवरफ़्लो
كومة أكثر من التدفق
スタックオーバーフロー
```

Comment: Sorry, that didnt work, still showing boxes! How do i know if it is supported?

Comment: It seems like changing the font on the console to Courier New supports more non-english langauges like Arabic, chinese, japanese, etc. Its better, but still doesnt show some scripts like Bangla